# How to use loop in creating multiple pdf file in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/postgredb.class.php';
require_once 'include/functions.php';
require_once("/tools/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$con=new PostgreDB(); 
ob_start();

$html =
    '<html><body>'.
    '<p>Hello World!</p>'.
    '<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>'.
    '</body></html>';

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{


$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("Admit card.pdf",array("Attachment"=>0));
}



?>
```

I want to print the "Hello World" in each page,but my code is printing it in only one page.
How do i print "Hello World" in each page using a loop.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Your loop is wrong. The way you add pages to your PDF is probably wrong. Apparently you are overwriting one page again and again instead of attaching a new one.

```
$html = <<<HTML
  <html>
      <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                /* Your document styling goes here */
            </style>
      </head>
      <body>
HTML;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $html .= '<div style="page-break-after: always;"><p>Hello World!</p></div>';
}
$html .= '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("Admit card.pdf",array("Attachment"=>0));
$dompdf->clear();
```

NOTE: You need to make sure, is that heredoc closer `HTML` is in a new line and not indented.

Comment: It works.Thank you so much for helping.I got the concept now.

Comment: Ok accepted.Is there any other way to create looping without embedding the "$html" again and again.I mean when i tried for showing only one page pdf, the total php code worked without the adding "$html" .How can the total php code will be put into a loop that will produce multiple pdf file.Any solution???

Comment: use full directory path with .jpg image to display image in pdf

Comment: @MangeshParte This code generated the three files but how can I save these pdf files because pdf files are opened in the web browser not saved in the computer.